# Review pane tweak

Tags: feature-request, review-page

The review pane is confusing to work with, and should have a collapse button of something so that you can review each post one by one. Whenever you click "Review Answer", there is no way to collapse it back or even differeniate between the layouts of "reviewing current answer" and "yet to review answers".

Is there an easier way to implement this? Either with a collapse button or a layout configuration?

Comment: I don't see the review pane anymore, all I see is blond, redhead... Although my tip would be to refresh the page occasionally, and work from the bottom.

Comment: Yes, and also skip the ones that have already been reviewed and edited by peers, or mark the ones you've already reviewed and okayed.

Comment: They automatically disappear after two people have opened them: You need to open the post to review it properly, really. By open I mean click "Review post"

Comment: Ok, thanks Stuart! :)